# Execute a shell script on another Linux server

Tags: linux

I have two different RHEL machines, say machine A and machine B, and below is my scenario.
On Machine B: I have created the below script `test.sh` under folder `/home/myuser/`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Executing Script on Remote Machine"
pwd
echo "Script is successfully Executed"
```

Now from machine A, I want to execute the `test.sh`, so could you please let me know what ssh command should I use?

Comment: `ssh B /home/myuser/test.sh`

Comment: Thanks, the above command worked for me, however it's populating password screen, so how I can pass the password in same command? I am hitting below command:

ssh  myuser@10.11.33.44  /home/myuser/test.sh

Comment: You should configure a public key so it doesn't use a password. That's not a programming question. You should use [unix.se] to ask questions about using Unix.